# Can anyone see what's wrong with this html on a mobile device?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

http://home.comcast.net/~maria.pettit/healthmutt/

It looks fine in the most common browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari & IE) and in Chrome on a GN, GS3 and an iPad it looks fine, but the main content text is oddly left-floating on the default Android browser (except for that one float-right image).

It creates about 25% white space on the right side of the content box on the default Android browser, and it doesn't make any sense at all. Also, why does that one image (Healthmutt05edit.png) float correctly? The text should be over there with it.

I've tried about everything to make it work. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my phone.  What Android phone and version?  (On Android: Settings -> About Phone -> get BUILDNUMBER and Model Number),

Comment: On the Galaxy Nexus the build number is JRO030, the Galaxy SIII is an SCH-I535 build cm_d2vzw-userdebug 4.2.1. Bear in mind that the site looks fine in Chrome on both phones; it's only the default browser that has the issue (on both devices).

Comment: was this problem solved?

Comment: It looks off-center in Chrome on desktop. The body has `width: 95%;`. Try removing that altogether?

Answer (score 0):

In my Android phone, if I zoom out the page it rearranges it self to what it's supposed to look like.

Also, I would recommend putting that text in a paragraph `<p>` or setting it's div to float:left. That way the text doesn't have to assume where it's supposed to go, instead you can tell it through css.